# AdMob section hides at times in Phonegap app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, admob

I have published a Phonegap app to Play Store which has AdMob integrated. 
At the beginning the ad section is displayed below the app but at times it does not even display the ad section below the app.

Is it a problem with the AdMob configuration or an implementation issue in Android source? 
Let me know a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that at times there is no ad to display. At that point no ad will be shown. Check logcat. It will show whether an ad was available or not.